# Multiple User IDs from multiple Request IDs

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Like said on the facebook developer reference here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

i can retrieve multiple User IDs from multiple Request IDs with this javascript code:

```
function getMultipleRequests(requestIds) {
  FB.api('', {"ids": requestIds }, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
}
```

But it doesn't work for me, and i can't find any real example over the web.

This is my code:

```
function newInvite()
{
    var receiverUserIds = FB.ui({ 
        method: 'apprequests',
        message: 'message',
        title: 'title',
    }, 
    function(res){
        if (!res  ||  !res.request_ids) { /* user canceled */ return; }
        FB.api('',{"ids": res.request_ids }, function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
)}
```

I receive the following error in firebug console:

(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: ["2451125555242","254271541274626"]
type: "OAuthException"

Any ideas?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution:

```
var requests = res.request_ids.join(',');
FB.api('',{"ids": requests }, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```